# Codeigniter form validatiion with ajax not work

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, validation

I try to test the controller validation without ajax and it worked.
I try to test ajax out side form validation and it work.

but when I try to get form validation result in ajax it not work.

Tris is my controller

```
function ajax_form() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('ajax/ajax_input');
}

function test() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('myname', 'Name', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        echo 1;
    } else {

        echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

This is my view

```
 <div id="test"></div>
          <?php

          echo form_open('ajax/test', array('id'=>'sub')); 
          echo form_input('myname');
          echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
          echo form_close();
          ?>
          <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sub').submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

               $.ajax({
                   url:'test',
                   type:'POST',
                  data:{myname:$('#myname').val()},
                   success:function(data)
                   {
                      console.log(data);
                   }
               });// end ajax
            });//end btn click
        });//end ready

        </script>
```

I already spent 3 hours try to fix this but still not work. Hope u guy can help.

Update type.

Comment: first correct your `url` used in ajax and then use `type` option as `type:"POST"`

Comment: Got it, thank you!